# Delete all text before a specific character using vim

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I have used curl to grab a website's code and put it in a text file. I'd like to delete all text that isn't a link! Lucky for me, all links are inside quotes, so I just need to delete all lines without `https://` in them, which I have done using `:g!/https:\/\//d`. Now I need to delete everything to the left and right of the quotes.

Here is my dilemma:

LINE 1: `RetailShop.URLs.getProductComponents = "https://example.com?emptyparam="; // random code`
LINE 2: `random code action="https://example.com" name="morerandomcode"`

If I start by intending to delete everything to the left of the quotes, I would use something like this `:%s/^.*"//` but if you try it yourself, it wants to delete everything to the left of the **second** quote on line 1. That would delete my whole link. Let's say I use a space, `:%s/^.* "//` *(after the * and before the ")*, then it would work on line 1, but not on line 2. Then when I do line 2 with `:%s/^.*="//` it will delete my link in line 1 because of how the link ends.

I don't want to complicate this too much. Explicitly, **I need a command that deletes the FIRST quote in every line regardless of what characters come before it**.

Comment: [vi.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I didn't even know that existed, thank you.

Comment: More like an *alternative* place to ask now that SO clarified some of its rules.

Comment: Is the HTML you're running this on guaranteed to only have one link on each line? This obviously isn't true for webpages in general, but perhaps it is for you. I ask because you'll need to alter your technique if you want to handle multiple links per line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you want but, let's imagine this:

Before:

```
LINE 1: RetailShop.URLs.getProductComponents = "https://example.com?emptyparam="; // random code
LINE 2: random code action="https://example.com" name="morerandomcode"
```

After:

```
https://example.com?emptyparam=
https://example.com
```

The command is `:%norm! f"di"Vp`, which is

1. `%` range for the whole buffer, following command would be run over all lines, one by one.
2. `norm!` execute normal mode commands without mapped things, in it's original form.
3. `f"` goto first `"`
4. `di"` delete everything inside `"..."` and put it into unnamed register
5. `Vp` select whole line and paste over it from unnamed register

PS, in modern vim you can omit `f"`:

```
:%norm! di"Vp
```

PPS, if you really want to use regex, you can try following:

```
:%s#^.*\(https://\S\+\)".*#\1
```

Which will have the same effect (on a given example).
It matches the whole line and submatches an https:// url, which is then used in replacement for the whole line.

Comment: I love your answer, I have nothing against using norm. One last thing though. If I have a line like so: post="null" href="https://example.com" it will delete the second set of quotes that I'd like to keep, how can I use norm to possibly keep only quotes that have https inside of them?

Comment: Then probably regex solution would be simpler, @ex7lted, anyway, here it is with norm: `%norm! /https^Mdi"Vp`, where `^M` should be placed as `CTRL-V CTRL-M`